# Boost.MultiArray Beginner: How to get a 4D-Array with dynamic inner-array-sizes?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, multidimensional-array, boost-multi-array

i want to store some kind of distance-matrix (2D), where each entry has some alternatives (different coordinates). So i want to access the distance for example x=1 with x_alt=3 and y=3 with y_alt=1, looking in a 4-dim multi-array with array[1][3][3][1].

*The important thing to notice is the following: the 2 most inner arrays/vectors don't have the same size for different values of the outer ones.*

After a first init step, where i calculate the values, no more modifying is needed!

This should be easily possible with the use of stl-vectors:

```
vector<vector<vector<vector<double> > > >`extended_distance_matrix;
```

where i can dynamically iterate over the outer 2 dimensions and fill only as much alternatives to the inner 2 dimensions as i need (e.g. with push_back()).

**Questions:**

- Is this kind of data-structure definition possible with Boost.MultiArray? How?
- Is it a good idea to use Boost.MultiArray instead of the nested vectors? Performance (especially lookups! (Memory-layout))? Easy of use?

Thanks for any input!

*sascha*

PS: The boost documentation didn't help me. Maybe one can use multi_array_ref to get already sized arrays into the whole 4D-structure?

**Edit:**
At the moment i'm thinking of another approach: flattening the alternatives -> one bigger matrix with all the distances between the alternatives. Then i only need to calc the number of alternatives per node, build up the prefix sum (which is describing the matrix position/shift) and can then access the information in a 2-step-way.

*But my questions are still open.*

Comment: I have essentially the same question. Do you remember what you ended up using? Questioning if Boost.MultiArray is a good idea for a 4D structure. (I know this was almost 5 years ago...but any advice is appreciated.)

Comment: @snd - Don't know if it's too late, but what Anycorn suggested is essentially correct. You would initialize a 2D array of 2D arrays (if you have boost `ublas::matrix< ublas::matrix<double> > my4D(ySize, y_altSize);`). Then as you figure out the correct sizes of each inner matrix, you would call `my4D(yIndex, y_altIndex).resize(xSize, x_altSize);`

Comment: @snd If you can figure out the size of each dimension of the arrays before you initialize them, then you should be using `boost::multi_array<double, 4> my4D(boost::extents[xSize][x_altSize][ySize][y_altSize]);` and following along the guides found [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html). This should be much faster than the above approach due to data locality.

Comment: Thanks @NoseKnowsAll. I started using [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/), but this reminds me that I need to check the speed of Arma vs. Boost

Comment: @snd if you do benchmark it, make sure you turn off all the debug options that are on by default in boost's library. But yeah, Armadillo is probably the way to go if you want 3D arrays. I didn't know it could go to 4D though. Also, if you're only dealing with 2D arrays, I'd strongly suggest Eigen. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

it sounds like you need:

```
multi_array<ublas::matrix<type>,2>
```

Comment: A 2-dim array of 2-dim matrices? Could you please explain that in more detail? Where would you save the dynamic part (alternatives). How will this be indexed? The outer array is indexed by [x][y]. Maybe the id's of the object -> distance from x to y. But how should the alternative-chose be encoded? Now i have 4 more indexes (2 for each array part) for encoding an 2-index-information (one alternative-decision per id)? You see, i'm having problems understanding your proposal.

Answer (score 0):

Boost.MultiArray deals with contiguous memory (arranged logically in many dimensions) so it is difficult to add elements in the inner dimensions. MultiArrays can be dynamically resized, e.g. to add elements in any dimension, but this is a costly operation that almost certainly need (internally) reallocation and copying.

Because of that requirement MultiArray is not the best option. But from what you say it looks like a combination of the two would be appropriate to you.

`boost::multi_array<std::vector<std::vector<type>>, 2> data`

The very nice thing is that the indexing interface doesn't change with respect to `boost::multi_array<type, 4>`. For example `data[1][2][3][4]` still makes sense.

I don't know from your post how you handle the inner dimension but it could even make sense to use this:

`boost::multi_array<boost::multi_array<type>, 2>, 2> data`

In any case, unless you really need to do linear algebra I would stay away from `boost::ublas::array`, or at most use it for the internal array if `type` is numeric. `boost::multi_array<boost::ublas::array<type>, 2> data` which is mentioned in the other answer.